# List all lines containing the word under the cursor in helm

Tags: helm

Helm is very powerful, how to implement the feature to create a helm list/buffer to highlight all the lines containing the word currently under the cursor?

Comment: Have you tried `helm-swoop` or `helm-occur`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `helm-swoop` does by default. See [GitHub](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop) for more info.

If you specifically prefer to use a different `helm` search tool, you could probably configure it to do something similar.

Comment: Awesome package, quite dismal description in list-packages... The animation in the github shows what it does perfectly, but the description, not so much: "List the all lines to another buffer, which is able to squeeze
by any words you input. At the same time, the original buffer's
cursor is jumping line to line according to moving up and down
the list.". (Not blaming Brian Z for this of course).